# Finding an expression for $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$ that is more precise in floating point arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, floating-point

Assuming that both $x$ and $z$ have no representation errors, and that $\vert z^2 \vert \ll \vert x^2 \vert$. There must exist an expression for $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$ that is the same in exact arithmetic but more precise in floating point arithmetic, according to my teacher.

I cannot possibly figure out how to find such an expression. If we assume some error $(1+\epsilon)$ to be applied to every operation in the above expression (e.g. $x \cdot x$ becomes $(x \cdot x)(1 + \epsilon)$) there cannot possibly be a better expression for this right? I have already tried rewriting the expression but everything I find seems to only add more errors, as the expression cannot be simplified further. Am I missing something here? Or did my teacher ask something impossible from me?

Comment: You could do some contortions like $$\sqrt{x^2+z^2}=\frac{x^2+z^2}{|x|+\frac{z^2}{2|x|}}\sqrt{1+\frac{\frac{z^4}{4x^2}}{x^2+z^2}},$$ identifying $x^2$ and $z^2$ with the first two terms in the binomial formula $(a+\frac b2)^2=a^2+ab+\frac{b^2}4$.

Comment: You could use $|x|\sqrt{1+z^2/x^2}$ and then use the power series for $\sqrt{1+w}.$

Comment: So you get an exact expression: $$|x|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}\left(\frac zx\right)^{2k}$$ and the first terms will give you a good approximation.

Comment: If $x$ is positive, then you get the first to terms are: $$x\left(1+\frac{z^2}{2x^2}\right)=x+\frac{z^2}{2x}$$

Comment: "More precise" than what?

Comment: This operation has a lot of practical utility and therefore is exposed as a standard math function `hypot()` in many programming languages. Your teacher did not ask the impossible. There are various ways to achieve more accurate computation in fixed-precision floating-point arithmetic (as compared to a naive implementation). For a very accurate arrangement due to noted floating-point expert [William Kahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529704/780717) of mine on Stackoverflow.